# Duvida verb GET WebApi

Tags: c#, web-service, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-2

Atualmente tenho algumas composições em meu model que fazem relacionamento com outras tabelas do meu banco.

Quando fui montar o get para que me traga todos os dados relacionados, tive vários problemas e dúvidas e quando consegui resolver, não sei se é o correto.

O que fiz foi tirar a tipagem do método para que eu conseguisse retornar o JSON. Mas vi que vou ter muitas dificuldades quando eu for consumir esse serviço pelo fato de não vir tipo e no asp.net mvc eu estar esperando o model preenchido.

Como ficou:

```
public IQueryable GetVerb()
{
    var dados = from d in db.Tabela1
                join a in db.Tabela2 on d.Tabela1_Tabela2Id equals a.Tabela2Id
                select new 
                {
                    nome = d.Nome,
                    cnpj = d.CNPJ,
                    endereco = a.Endereco,
                    cidade = a.Cidade,
                    cep = a.CEP,
                };

    return (dados);             
}
```

O que acontece é que não estou tipando com meu model Tabela1... Até retornou, mas como faço para que a WebApi me retorne também os models que tem relacionamento?

Já tentei `Tabela1.Include()` e não deu certo, me retornou erro StackOverflow...

O que eu poderia fazer para resolver essa questão? Um ViewModel poderia resolver?

## EDIT

Tabela1

```
public partial class Tabela1
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Tabela1()
    {
        
    }

    public long Tab1Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Tab1_EndId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Tab1_PesId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Tab1_RmcId { get; set; }
    public string Tab1Nome { get; set; }
    public string Tab1Apelido { get; set; }
    public string Tab1Cnpj { get; set; }

  
    public virtual Tabela2 Tabela2 { get; set; }
    
}
```

Tabela2

```
public partial class Tabela2
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Tabela2()
    {
        this.Tabela1= new HashSet<Tabela1>();
    }

    public long Tab2Id { get; set; }
    public int Tab2_UfeId { get; set; }
    public string Tabela2 { get; set; }
    public string Tab2Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Tab2Cidade { get; set; }
    public int Tab2Cep { get; set; }

  
    public virtual ICollection<Tabela1> Tabela1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: **1**. Qual a intenção do Join se em nenhum lugar são usados os dados da segunda tabela? **2**. Qual o problema com o `Include`? Não era pra dar StackOverflow, isso deve ser outro problema, dê mais detalhes. **3**. Por que está retornando um `IQueryable`?

Comment: @jbueno, em ordem: São usados sim os dados, mas no MVC, na view. Então, eu não sei o que acontece quando chamo o include... O erro é gerado e não me retorna nada. IQueryable porque já estava assim quando criei o controller no web api...

Comment: Se você não especificar no `select` os dados da segunda tabela, eles não vão existir dentro de `dados`. Qual é erro exato que você recebe ao usar o Include?

Comment: Me retorna o erro Stack Overflow...

Comment: Cara, dizer só isso não vai ajudar. Tem que ter a stack trace, a mensagem também deve ter mais detalhes. Se deu StackOverflow existe algum motivo, mas sem mais detalhes é impossível de saber.

Comment: Eu queria popular o model Tabela1 porque no MVC eu espero esse model populado pra mostrar os dados na view

Comment: Entendi! Assim que eu chegar em casa eu pego o Stack trace e coloco na pergunta... Aí eu te marco, pode ser?

Comment: @jbueno o que me retorna no stack trace é: `System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll
 ` e informando que eu posso estar fazendo um loop infinito...

Comment: Então você tem dependências circulares... Poste os models.

Comment: Meus models são criados pelo entity em database first.. Tem algum problema?

Comment: @jbueno, models na pergunta!

Comment: Você tem referência do pai no filho e do filho no pai. Isso que tá causando o Stackoverflow

Comment: @jbueno, funcionou! Olha, muito obrigado mesmo!!!!! Poderia colocar como resposta? Mesmo que seja simples!

Comment: Ok. Vou colocar, depois melhoro. Tô pelo celular agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas remova a referência da classe pai na classe filha (ou ao contrário) e use o include.

Esse tipo de referência circular é que está causando o Stackoverflow.