# Consumir web api com varios models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Nessa minha pergunta [Duvida verb GET WebApi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192819/duvida-verb-get-webapi) eu enfrente algum erro por conta dos relacionamentos. Mas agora pegando ela como base por conta dos meus models, como eu poderia consumir esse serviço? Porque o model Tabela1 tem relacionamentos e eu precisava traze-los para o MVC que eu estou usando para consumir... Mas o que acontece é que os relacionamentos, os models, não vem preenchidos, vem nulos...

Meu controller no asp.net mvc:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Varialvel resposável por receber os dados que estão no banco de dados para mostrar na tela
        HttpResponseMessage resposta = cliente.GetAsync("http://meuservico/api/servico").Result;

        //Se der tudo certo, é porque trouxe os dados retornando código 200
        if (resposta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //Formata o json para mostrar na tela
            var result = resposta.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Tabela1>>().Result;

            //retorna para a tela os json formatado
            return View(result);
        }

        //Caso tenha dado errado, retorna somente a tela sem dado algum
        return View();
    }
```

A variavel result traz o model Tabela1 preechido, mas os seus relacionamentos não... O que poderia estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com o código da resposta do link:

```
public IQueryable GetVerb()
{
    var dados = from d in db.Tabela1
                join a in db.Tabela2 on d.Tabela1_Tabela2Id equals a.Tabela2Id
                select new 
                {
                    nome = d.Nome,
                    cnpj = d.CNPJ,
                    endereco = a.Endereco,
                    cidade = a.Cidade,
                    cep = a.CEP,
                };

    return (dados);             
}
```

O método `GetVerb()` retorna uma lista de um genérico que foi criado no `select`. Então, se vc está restringindo de retornar todos os registros de `Tabela1` junto com seus relacionamentos `Tabela2`, não tem como os consumidores de sua API receberem esses dados.

```
public IQueryable GetVerb()
{
    var dados = from d in db.Tabela1
                join a in db.Tabela2 on d.Tabela1_Tabela2Id equals a.Tabela2Id
                select new 
                {
                    nome = d.Nome,
                    cnpj = d.CNPJ,
                    endereco = a.Endereco,
                    cidade = a.Cidade,
                    cep = a.CEP,
                    tabela2 = a // <====
                };

    return (dados);             
}
```

Por último, torne todo seu fluxo assíncrono:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var response = await cliente.GetAsync("http://meuservico/api/servico");
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return View();

    var list = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Table1>>();
    return View(list);
}
```

Comment: E no caso de usar um Include? Digo Tabela1.Include(x => x.Tabela2); Funciona dá mesma forma?

Comment: Mas daí vc estará usando `Lambda Expressions` com `Fluent API` e não apenas `Linq to SQL`. O que eu acho muito melhor, e bem mais simples. Bastaria fazer algo como `db.Tabela1.Include(t => t.Tabela2)`. Mas não esqueça de [definir os relacionamentos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx)  antes.

Comment: Então, no web api fiz assim e funcionou... Mas é no ASP.net MVC... Como posso consumir dessa forma? Já tem todos os relacionamentos...

Comment: Linq, Lambda expressions, fluent api, nenhum tem dependência com System.Web. Vc pode usalos até com console app.

Comment: Poderia incrementar a resposta dessa forma que me mostrou então?